Error intermitente de getDataRange en Apps Script con llamadas a la API
Estoy haciendo un sistema de lectura de productos a través de una API en una hoja de cálculo de Google Sheets, haciendo un GET request con el ID y el programa devuelve el nombre del producto. Funciona bastante bien, hago las solicitudes desde PostMan y devuelve casi siempre el nombre correspondiente, pero 1 de cada 15 o 16 veces salta el siguiente error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getDataRange') (line 8, file "code")

El código de Apps Script:

function doGet(e){
  let wbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let wsheet = wbook.getSheetById(0);
  let data = wsheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  const idColumn = 1;
  const nameColumn = 2;
  const idRequested = e.parameter.id;

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    let row = i;
    let currentId = data[row][idColumn];

    if(currentId == idRequested){
      let result = data[row][nameColumn];
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
    }
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("null").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}

Lo que me está costando es que no salta el error siempre, si no el 5% de las veces, constantemente.
El código está dentro del Sheet.

Estás leyendo las hojas por ID, estás seguro que los ID son válidos? No sería mejor acceder a la primera hoja y ya ?

@Excorpion sí, los ID son válidos, pero igual voy a intentar hacer lo que me decís, muchas gracias

Mientras espero respuesta del comentario, podemos analizar el problema.
El error dice: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getDataRange'), es decir, no puede leer las propiedades de un NULL
Esto ocurre cuando haces: let data = wsheet.getDataRange().getValues(), y data al ser null no posee propiedades, por lo que no se puede realizar el for que viene más abajo.
Entonces, realicemos un control del error, y cuando sea NULL, hagamos lo siguiente:
if (!data || data.length === 0) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("null: no se encontro informacion").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}

Por otro lado, lo que mencionaba antes, que si entras al ID, y este no existe como tal, siempre te toparas con problemas, lo mejor sería entrar a la primera hoja, sin importar el ID.
wsheet = wbook.getSheets()[0];

Por último, si la variable como tal no la vas a estar reasignando, usa const en vez de let.
const wbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const wsheet = wbook.getSheets()[0];
const data = wsheet.getDataRange().getValues();


Hice bastantes intentos luego de aplicar todas las soluciones que me indicaste y no saltó ningún error, así que supongo que está solucionado, muchísimas gracias

@nachosar siempre tienes que ir mirando los errores y viendo si cambiaron o no
